# Starting Meteor dev from NPM scripts causes CPU spike

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, package.json

Picking up on a [suggestion I read](http://blog.differential.com/use-package-json-in-your-meteor-app-for-fun-profit/), I thought I would try starting my Meteor processes in dev mode from npm scripts in `package.json` files, since I have some verbose startup settings. I'm aware that I can use a bash script or the like but `npm run whatever` seemed like a nice clean solution.

Unfortunately doing this causes huge CPU spikes that render my system unusable. For example, running `meteor -p 6001` and `meteor -p 7001` yields two node processes utilizing 0.3% CPU each. But running `npm run appA` and `npm run appB` where the scripts point to the same commands above yields a first node process utilizing over 70% of CPU, and a second process over 100%.

Apparently this is not doing what I thought it was doing. It's not mission-critical but I'd love to learn what's going on under the hood or, even better, a fix. I'm running node version `5.4.1` and Meteor version `1.2.1` (which utilizes node version 0.10.40).

Can someone explain what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same thing happened here, glad to find out that this is because of npm script, I was thinking that I'm due to deep profiling my app to find what's wrong.

Would love an explanation and a fix too.